# Gaussian surface enclosing two charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, gauss-law, flow

I'm trying to use the following exercise as a launch pad to help me understand Gaussian surfaces and their applications to flux:

[image]

For (a), I posit that all the charges contribute to the electric field at point $P$, as I don't see why this wouldn't be the case. All the charges have their own electric field, so at point $P$, the net electric field should be a total contribution from all of them.

For (b), $q_1$ and $q_4$, I believe, are the answer to this question. The net flux leaving the Gaussian surface is proportional to the enclosed charge.

For (c) and (d), guidance is needed for me.

In (c), I'm slightly confused by what it's exactly asking for. My hunch is to find the net electric field contribution and dot product it with the area vector to find the flux threading the circular area, and equate it to $\frac{q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0}$. However, I don't see a line of reasoning where all the charges affecting the flux being the obvious answer - I don't see why this wouldn't be the case.

For (d), I believe I have to write the integral I theorized in (c), although I don't know how to express $\vec{dA}$ in $Flux = \int \vec E * \vec {dA} = \frac{q_{encl}}{\epsilon_0}$, although I don't know what I would express as $\vec E$, hypothesizing that $\vec {dA}$ is a vector on in the y direction.

Comment: (c) I am not to sure about the term flux is **threading** the area. If it means crossing the area, than the circle is simply a part of the gaussian surface in ***whatever*** orientation and ***whatever*** shape. So all charges contribute to this flux. (d) This question seems unrelated to (c). Simply asking about the total flux crossing the ***whole*** gaussian envelope.

Answer (score 1):

The system of charges you are considering is shown in this image where I have used two plastic tumblers to show the **closed** Gaussian surface $G$ and surface $P$ is also shown with $\hat p$ being in the plane of the xy plane which is the piece of white paper..

[image]

Parts **b** and **d** are linked in that they are asking you about the closed Gaussian surface and the electric flux through that closed surface.
As the surface is closed there is no doubt which of the charges are enclosed within the surface - $q_1$ and $q_4$ - and they provide the net flux through the Gaussian surface which you can find by applying Gauss' Law..

The surface $P$ is not closed as there is no clearly defined inside and outside and so one can think of parts **a** and **c** as being related.
All the charges contribute to the electric field in the region of surface $P$ and also contribute to the electric flux through surface $P$.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to arrange this for me. Just for clarification, you drew $q_4$ and $q_3$ in the plane in a clever way so the picture looks like it's *inside* the surface like required?

Comment: @sangstar q1 and q4 are within the Gaussian surface.